# How to install Python packages for a VS Code virtual environment?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I follow the command in the VS Code Python tutorial to install a package in the virtual environment, the script only runs successfully using the global interpreter, not the newly created virtual environment.

I am following the VS Code Python tutorial step-by-step trying to learn the proper uses of the IDE (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial). The previous step that I completed was to create the virtual environment and select it in the **Python: Select Interpreter** command, see below.
[Tutorial previous step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwGnv.png)
The next step gives the instructions on how to install the matplotlib package: `py -m pip install matplotlib`
When I try to rerun the script in the next step, the debugger tells me: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'`
If I switch to the global Python interpreter, the script successfully runs.

My question is why does the Python package not install to the virtual environment when I am working in it and only to the global interpreter? Also, how do I install packages only for these virtual environments?

Maybe this is good feedback to VS Code showing that their tutorial is missing something obvious for a new user!

Answer (score 1):

Below is the link for reference documentation :-

```
https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#creating-a-virtual-environment
```

To create virtual enivornment named env:-

```
py -m venv env
```

To activate enivornment:-

```
.\env\Scripts\activate
```

For installing module check if pip is upto  date or run

```
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

After the environment creation you must select the new interpreter (ctrl+shift+P). If it is not listed, then search it using "+ Enter interpreter path..." option and select the venv installation path.
After environment selection you must open a new terminal and if the environment is correctly activated, then you should see the environment name as first string of each new terminal line. Your new environment is ready to be modified!!
Now you can install any lib you need by the terminal when your env is activated, using (if windows OS) `py -m pip install <lib_name>`.
Remember that your current interpreter is defined by the first string of each new line in your terminal (before the current path). If no env name is printed it means you are using the global interpreter.